# Is there a way to create socket connection between two devices which aren't in the same network?

Tags: android, macos, networking, network-programming

I'm planning to develop an app that transmits data over Wi-Fi from one device to other (similar to AirDrop or Wifi Direct). I couldn't find a way to create a connection between two devices. Initially, I thought creating a hotspot from one device and connecting to it with other device is a good idea. Is it possible to do it in Mac, PC and Android programmatically.

Basically, my real question is that how can I send data to a device over Wi-Fi which isn't in the same network?

Comment: `Initially, I thought creating a hotspot from one device and connecting to it with other device is a good idea.`. It is. And very well possible.

Comment: If they use the same wifi network then it is possible too and both devices can be server or client.

Comment: If both devices use wifi but they are not in the same network then boht devices can be server and client. The client should use the public ip of the router of the server and the router should forward requests to the wifi client device.

Comment: If both devices use mobile connection then server/client communication is not possible.

Comment: If one device uses mobile connection then your sever should run on the one using wifi.

Comment: The code for client and server in all these scenarios is the same. Only the ip used by the client will be different.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my question. I need to connect my devices directly. Think of AirDrop or Wifi Direct technologies. There shouldn't be a need of a router. In your way of thinking, even hotspot is not required. I'm sorry if my sentences sound rude. English is not my native language.

Comment: Look at my first comment. There i tell you that you very well can use a hotspot. The other comments are bonus. I gave you the bonusses because `my real question is that how can I send data to a device over Wi-Fi which isn't in the same network?` did not match using a hotspot.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. Do you know how can I create a hotspot from terminal on a mac. There aren't any useful resources about this topic. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: No, sorry no mac's here.